# HTTP Status 404 - /UESProject/

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

I cloned project from GitHub and now i have two web.xml files in project and one in server.

In every of them, I set `pocetna.jsp` as welcome page but when I run application on server I still get HTTP 404 error[image]

Comment: aren't you supposed to have a single web.xml

Comment: @Humza I just clone repositorium with my friend's project and now we trying to run it on my computer. Code is fine and everything works on his computer. I don't even have idea how I have 3 web.xml

Comment: can you share repo link

Comment: @Humza Sure: https://github.com/sblagojcic/UESProject.git